# quickly toggle RTS manually when RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE is enabled

Tags: windows, winapi, serial-port

On Windows XP, I've got a standard (on the motherboard) RS-232 serial port opened and configured with

```
dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE;
```

This works fine for my needs.

Now while there is no RX pending, I sometimes need to briefly toggle the RTS line under the control of my application.  I can't just call EscapeCommFunction, as that fails when RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE is enabled.

I tried to this:

```
dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE; // manual RTS control and turns on RTS
SetCommState( hDevice, &dcb );
dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE; // turns off RTS since there is no TX pending
SetCommState( hDevice, &dcb );
```

However, this never seems to work. I never see RTS toggle.  It's like the device driver notices that I just set RTS and am clearing it now, so it just aborts what I was doing.

If I put a sleep in there:

```
dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE; // turn on RTS
SetCommState( hDevice, &dcb );
Sleep(1);
dcb.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_TOGGLE; // turns off RTS since there is no TX pending
SetCommState( hDevice, &dcb );
```

Then I see the toggle, but it's extremely variable in length, anywhere from 1 to 15 ms (which is to be expected I guess).  I use timeBeginPeriod to setup 1ms scheduling and my thread is already high priority (should I go to real time priority?).

So, is there something I can to do "flush" the RTS change to the hardware so I don't have to do the Sleep?  I can busy wait (using QueryPerformanceCounter to wait for the amount of time I want), but I'm concerned that this would still not "flush" the RTS change to the device.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the serial port I was using to monitor the RTS line was faulty.  It was USB based and was missing the short transitions.

I put an O-scope on it and I can see a 1ms blip when I just toggle RTS on/off as I tried initially.